# jquery dynamic add file fields

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hello I want to do something like this :
[image: Here is example]
I want to do after click "+" add 2 new fields with indexed name+1, and after click "-" I want to delete this fields.

Comment: I don't know how to get started. I have form with one file input, but  I don't know how add/delete dynamic next fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satishJS/xMpwv/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="main_div">

  <div id="div_1">
    <div style="float:left">
        <label>Textbox 1 </label><input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <label>Textbox 2 </label><input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <label class="cursor_plus" onclick="add_Textbox();">+</label><label class="cursor_minus" onclick="remove_Textbox();">-</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
<script>
var counter = 1;
function add_Textbox()
{
    counter = counter + 1;
    var second = counter *2;
        var first = second - 1;
        var html = '<div id="div_'+counter+'" style="clear:both;">';
            html += '<div style="float:left">';
            html += '<label>Textbox '+first+' </label><input type="text" name="text'+first+'" id="text'+first+'">';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div style="float:left">';
            html += '<label>Textbox '+second+' </label><input type="text" name="text'+second+'" id="text'+second+'">';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div style="float:left">';
            html += '<label class="cursor_plus" onclick="add_Textbox();">+</label><label class="cursor_minus" onclick="remove_Textbox();">-</label>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
    document.getElementById('main_div').innerHTML += html;      
}

function remove_Textbox()
{
    if(counter==1)
    {
        alert("Cant' remove remaining One Only !!");
    }
    else
    {
        var id_rem = "div_"+counter+"";
        (elem=document.getElementById(id_rem)).parentNode.removeChild(elem)
        counter = counter - 1;  
    }   
}

</script>
```

**CSS :**

```
<style>
.cursor_plus{float:left; font-weight:bold; color:green; cursor:pointer}
.cursor_minus{float:left;margin-left:5px;font-weight:bold; color:red; font-size:12px; cursor:pointer}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var i=1;
$('#pl').click(function(){ $(this).parents('.ch').prepend($('<input/>').attr({'type':'file','name':i,'id':i}));
    i++;
});
$('#mn').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.ch').children('input').first().remove();
i--;
})
```

If I understood your question properly It may help

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t8jQ6/1/)

Comment: Almost, because I would like to be added once the two fields :) Thanks for the reply!